# How to connect to an already existing database in python

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I made a database using mongoose on express js. Then when I try to access that database in python using pymongo it creates a new database with same name on same connection and new collections. Below is my connection code in python

```
import pymongo
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/fileUpoadStats')
file1 = connection.fileStats
cursor = file1.find()
for doc in cursor:
    print doc
```

I want to access the same database in python. Can anyone help?

Comment: import pymongo
mongoclient= pymongo.MongoClient(host='your ip')['your db name']

Comment: Didn't I already do that? It creates a new database with same name @pushpendrachauhan

Comment: No it is not. It creates a new database with new collection and data in them @Galen

Comment: @AditModi Please see the two answers to the question I suggested as a duplicate. There are not two databases with the same name. The name is a unique identifier of the database (case-insensitive). There must be something else going on, like a non-printing character in one of the database names.

Comment: @Galen No this is not the answer to my question. I made one database on express and mongoose and I want to access it in python